# How to configure atmosphere and meteor with spring mvc using Java annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-java-config, atmosphere

I am using AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer to configure my application beside WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[]{"/"};
        }

        @Override
        protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
            CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
            characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
            characterEncodingFilter.setForceRequestEncoding(true);
            characterEncodingFilter.setForceResponseEncoding(true);
            return new Filter[]{new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(), new MultipartFilter(), characterEncodingFilter};
        }


     }
```

so the question is how to configure meteor servlet in my application?

Any help?